# HTTP 500 error when calling REST service using C#

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-web-api

I'm Getting HTTP 500 error when calling following REST via c#, but I was able to do the POST by using chrome REST Console

#### Request body sent ( Got from REST console)

```
Request Url: http://dev-6666.amazonaws.com/CourseEnrollment
Request Method: POST
Status Code: 201
Params: {
    "MESSAGE-TYPE": "UserEnrollmentCreate",
    "PAYLOAD": "<userstd version=\"\"\"\"><user password=\"\"PSEUDO-5621b55a\"\" lastname=\"\"Wara\"\" emailaddress=\"\"student3@bloody.com\"\" loginid=\"\"BloodyStudent3\"\" firstname=\"\"Buddihi\"\" userid=\"\"19658121\"\" clientid=\"\"117112\"\" createdate=\"\"2014-04-29T03:55:54.873\"\" lastupdate=\"\"2014-05-29T03:55:54.873\"\"><userproperty propertyname=\"\"\"\" propertyvalue=\"\"\"\" createdate=\"\"\"\" lastupdate=\"\"\"\"></userproperty></user></userstd>"
}
```

C# method used (This is the one getting 500 error)

```
 private void TestCreateUser()
        {

            string requestData = "{\"MESSAGE-TYPE\":UserEnrollmentCreate,\"PAYLOAD\":\"<userstd version=\"\"\"\"><user password=\"\"PSEUDO-5621b55a\"\" lastname=\"\"Wara\"\" emailaddress=\"\"student3@bloody.com\"\" loginid=\"\"BloodyStudent3\"\" firstname=\"\"Buddihi\"\" userid=\"\"19658121\"\" clientid=\"\"117112\"\" createdate=\"\"2014-04-29T03:55:54.873\"\" lastupdate=\"\"2014-05-29T03:55:54.873\"\"><userproperty propertyname=\"\"\"\" propertyvalue=\"\"\"\" createdate=\"\"\"\" lastupdate=\"\"\"\"></userproperty></user></userstd>}";

            byte[] data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(requestData);
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://dev-6666.amazonaws.com/CourseEnrollment");
            request.Method = "POST";
            request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();
            dataStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
            dataStream.Close();

            WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
            string result = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
        
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

form-url-encoded data should be in form (variablename)=(data)&(variablename)=(data)....

The console representation is a bit messy, so the real data string should be

```
string requestData = "MESSAGE-TYPE=UserEnrollmentCreate&PAYLOAD=<userstd version=\"\"\"\"><user password=\"\"PSEUDO-5621b55a\"\" lastname=\"\"Wara\"\" emailaddress=\"\"student3@bloody.com\"\" loginid=\"\"BloodyStudent3\"\" firstname=\"\"Buddihi\"\" userid=\"\"19658121\"\" clientid=\"\"117112\"\" createdate=\"\"2014-04-29T03:55:54.873\"\" lastupdate=\"\"2014-05-29T03:55:54.873\"\"><userproperty propertyname=\"\"\"\" propertyvalue=\"\"\"\" createdate=\"\"\"\" lastupdate=\"\"\"\"></userproperty></user></userstd>";
```

Answer (score 1):

The response should have been 400 in a working implementation as you specify `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` while you post `application/json` as content.

WebApi probably returns 500 as it tried to decode the content as a form while the content actually is JSON, hence it get's an exception and therefore return 500 as status code.